# Kendo UI - How to have SQL Populated Grid Filter Second SQL Populated Grid On Click?

Tags: php, javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that has a unique identifier and when I click a row, I want it to display details in the second grid.  Both datasets are populated from a php file that link to a database.  So the second grid shows all the details for that unique identifier.

First Grid:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                      pageSize: 100,
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://localhost:8888/stationslist.php",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: "data",
                            total: function(response) {
                                return $(response.data).length;
                                }
                            } 
                            },


                    selectable: "single",
                    sortable: {
                        mode: "multiple",
                        allowUnsort: true
                    },
                    change: function (arg) {
                        var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
                            return $(item).find('td').first().text();
                            });
                          }
```

Second Grid:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid2").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                      pageSize: 100,
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://localhost:8888/spots.php",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: "data",
                            total: function(response) {
                                return $(response.data).length;
                                }
                            } 
                            }
```

Comment: Do you have seen this implementation?  http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

Comment: Yes, I have.  But I don't want it to show up within the same grid, I want it to be in a separate grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `change` handler for the first `grid` as:

```
change    : function (e) {
    var item = this.dataItem(this.select());
    populateGrid2(item);
}
```

Where we get as `item` all the information from the selected row (you don't need that complex `$.map`) and then invoke a second function for populating the second `grid`.

You should consider not recreating `grid` each time that one raw is selected but repopulating it. If so, initialize `grid2` as:

```
$("#grid2").kendoGrid({
    dataSource : {
        pageSize : 100,
        transport: {
            read        : {
                url     : "http://localhost:8888/spots.php",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (arg, op) {
                if (op === "read") {
                    return { id: arg.id }
                }
            }
        },
        schema   : {
            data : "data",
            total: function (response) {
                return $(response.data).length;
            }
        }
    },
    autoBind: false
});
```

Where we say not to auto-bind (do not read data until we explicitly say it) and then define a `parameterMap` function for managing the arguments (sending the `id` to the server).

Now, the function `populateGrid2` is just:

```
function populateGrid2(item) {
    var ds = $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    ds.filter({ field: "Identifier", operator: "eq", value: item.Identifier });
}
```

Simple, elegant and efficient!

You can find `filter` documentation in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter)

Comment: that works in the sense that it causes the second grid to populate and refresh with each click on the first grid.  however, it is not filtering the second grid.  it just shows everything.  each datasource has a field called "Identifier" that should be the filter field.  Which part of what you posted is causing the filtering?

Comment: I thought that the filtering was done by the server. So what you want is that the filtering gets done in the client. Correct?

Comment: correct.  the spots.php just contains everything.  so when you click, it will just filter it at that point.

Comment: i don't think that the change function is grabbing the value in the identifier field, so therefore it is not displaying any data.  we are close though, because when i change item.id to a text value, it works.

Comment: Of course instead of `item.id` you need to say the field name. I don't know the name of the fields on your original grid so I just assume that it was `id`. You can display which ones are available adding as first sentence `alert(JSON.stringify(item,null,4));` in `populateGrid2` function.